# Magento 2: Docker implementation in local

Tags: magento2

How to run magento 2 usig docker? shall implement in local for run magento 2 using or creating docker ,I need to know how to implement docker with magento 2 in local kindly help me?

Comment: Make sure elastic search is working properly in dokcer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to follow some tutorials to understand how docker works. Here is a great start: https://tech.osteel.me/posts/docker-for-local-web-development-part-1-a-basic-lemp-stack

Just doing part 1 of that tutorial can clear up a lot of things. I highly recommend it.

If you need a quick setup, you can copy some of my settings from here for Magento 2 install:
[Nginx throwing 404 - Magento 2 Docker Environment for Windows 10](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315051/nginx-throwing-404-magento-2-docker-environment-for-windows-10)

There is also good tutorial from MageModule team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTXRYKRldiU

Comment: sure i will check on this .. i have a doubt shall i implement this in local environment is this possible?

Comment: Yes, I have been using Docker + WSL2 for last 2 months to develop front-end and backend M2 code. It works well.

If you want to skip all that, just get Ubuntu machine and install M2 there. But you will not have ability to switch your environment on a whim like you can with Docker.

Comment: thanks..sure will check and update here

Answer (score 3):

I took the magento cloud docker

https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud-docker

I pulled it apart and got open source running on it

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Magento2CloudDocker

Then wrote a quickstart  guide

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Magento2CloudDocker/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md

I've got 2.4 running with elastic search

I hope this helps someone